# How to move jar files between jobs in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, artifacts

I am trying to build a gitlab pipeline to build a docker image from a java app. I have two artifacts, that I would like to pass between the build stages... One file (build_result.txt) is found an uploaded, but the other, (chat.jar) cannot be found. But, both files are in the same directory. Is there a size or extension limit for uploading files as artifacts?

---

```
stages:

  - app-build
  - con-build

image: docker:latest
  
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  #Global variables
  GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "true"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

 #Application variables 
  APP_NAME: web
  APP_TAG: test

before_script:
  - echo "..."

after_script:
  - echo "..."

app-build:
  stage: app-build
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - build_result.txt 
      - chat.jar
    expire_in: 2 days
  tags: 
    - dind
  script:
    - echo "BEFORE..."
    - apk --no-cache --update add maven git
    - apk --no-cache --update add openjdk11 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community

    - echo "DO..."
    - echo "building app..."| tee -a build_result.txt 
    - git clone https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-websocket-chat-demo.git /app
    - cd /app
    - mvn package | tee -a build_result.txt
    - cp target/websocket-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/chat.jar
    - ls / 
    - ls /app 
    - ls /app/target

con-build:
  stage: con-build
  dependencies:
    - app-build
  tags: 
    - dind
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - docker_build.txt
    expire_in: 2 days

  script:
    - echo "Place artifact for docker consumption"
    - mkdir -p /docker/files/app
    - cp chat.jar /docker/files/app/chat.jar
    - cd docker
    - docker build -t "$APP_NAME:$APP_TAG" . | tee -a docker_build.txt
```

and the output I get is that the chat.jar can't be found, but it is in the same directory... At the end of the build stage log show as warning, but the next jobs fails saying it can't find the file ... How can it find one file and not the other?

step 1 - log.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time:  18.574 s
 [INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-24T18:15:56Z
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 $ cp target/websocket-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/chat.jar
 $ ls /
 app
 bin
 builds
 certs
 dev
 etc
 home
 lib
 media
 mnt
 opt
 proc
 root
 run
 sbin
 srv
 sys
 tmp
 usr
 var
 $ ls /app
 Dockerfile
 Readme.md
 build_result.txt
 chat.jar
 k8s-deployment.yaml
 mvnw
 mvnw.cmd
 pom.xml
 screenshot.png
 src
 target
 $ ls /app/target
 classes
 generated-sources
 generated-test-sources
 maven-archiver
 maven-status
 surefire-reports
 test-classes
 websocket-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 websocket-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
Running after_script
00:00
 Running after script...
 $ echo "do stuff after every stage..."
 do stuff after every stage...
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:00
 Uploading artifacts...
 build_result.txt: found 1 matching files and directories 
 WARNING: chat.jar: no matching files               
 Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... ok  id=797950 responseStatus=201 Created token=nVg8i-GF
 Job succeeded
```

step 2 - log:

```
 $ cp chat.jar /docker/files/app/chat.jar
 cp: can't stat 'chat.jar': No such file or directory
Running after_script
00:00
 Running after script...
 $ echo "do stuff after every stage..."
 do stuff after every stage...
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:00
 Uploading artifacts...
 WARNING: docker_build.txt: no matching files       
 ERROR: No files to upload                          
 ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `docker_build.txt` file with the content of
`echo "building app..."| tee -a build_result.txt`
but then you are changing the directory to `/app` and then you create another `docker_build.txt` and finally you build your artifact.

But you see your first `docker_build.txt` not with your `ls` command because your starting directory is not `/` but the a dynamic path provided by the `CI_PROJECT_DIR` [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)

Further all artifact defintions are also relativ to this path, therefore after moving your `docker_build.txt` command this should work:

```yaml
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - app/build_result.txt 
      - app/chat.jar
```